# Animation appears only when key is pressed, image disappears when no key is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, desktop-application

The screen is blank when no key is pressed, I want the animation to stop at the last image of the animation, but it disappears when no key is pressed. Here is my render method.

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
        batch.draw(right.getKeyFrame(time, true), 100, 0);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))batch.draw(left.getKeyFrame(time,true),100,0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling `batch.draw(...)` when neither RIGHT or LEFT are being pressed.

You need something like:

```
if ( Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) )
{
    batch.draw(right.getKeyFrame(time, true), 100, 0);
}
else if ( Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) )
{
    batch.draw(left.getKeyFrame(time, true), 100, 0);
}
else
{
    batch.draw(middle.getKeyFrame(time, true), 100, 0);
}
```

You need to replace the `middle` object with what you expect to see on the screen when no keys are pressed.

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. I tried simple if else but never thought or if elseif else structure. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Glad it works - could you please mark the answer as correct? ;)